# How does CUDA know to treat a void* as a symbol?

Tags: cuda

There's a thing in CUDA that completely perplexes me and I cannot figure out why it works.

Imagine you have some device variable, say

```
__device__ int d_foo;
```

If you want to read it, you write

```
int h_foo;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_foo, d_foo, sizeof(int));
```

However, this shouldn't even compile! If we look at the signature of `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol()` we can see it defined as

```
extern __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(void *dst, 
  const void *symbol, // <-- this part
  size_t count, size_t offset __dv(0), enum cudaMemcpyKind kind __dv(cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

As you can see, the second argument is a `void*`. A void pointer. I'm  feeding in an `int`. The parameter documentation states this should be a *device symbol address* but I'm not providing an address, am I?!? I mean, I'm passing in `d_foo` which is definitely not an address. Or, at least, it sure doesn't look like an address to me.

Can someone explain what is going on here? How does this thing even compile?

Answer (score 1):

The toolchain uses C++ templating tricks to overload the API function to make everything work. Internally, this is what the compiler uses:

```
template< class T> 
static inline cudaError_t 
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(void *dst, const T & symbol, size_t count, 
                     size_t offset = 0, cudaMemcpyKind kind = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) 
{ 
    return ::cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(dst, (const void *)(&symbol), count, offset, kind); 
}
```

which you can see exposes a template prototype that matches the canonical form of the call (passing the symbol), and internally casts the symbol reference to `void *` so that the API call argument is respected.

It is confusing, but I guess it was done this way to support both the old (pre-elf, symbols passed by name in a string) and new (elf, symbols passed directly) cubin formats during the transition between the two forms.

Comment: It gets even more interesting under the hood. &symbol is the *host* address which is not the address the GPU will have for that symbol. For global `__device__` variables compiler generates it's host-side twin which acts as a sort of proxy for the real device-side symbol and it tells CUDA runtime the address of the host-side proxy along with the device-side name. CUDA runtime APIs in turn will attempt to map addresses of host-side proxy to the real device-side pointers for the API calls that need it.